# How is this code not drawing a line through a point

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I have nodes `A` and `B` on the same horizontal line, and I have a ray from `B` inclined at an angle of `58` degrees with respect to the horizontal line.  To make a line through `B`, I want to have a ray through `B` inclined at an angle of `58 - 180 = -122` degrees.  I issue the command `\draw (B) -- ++(-122:1.5);`, but I am not getting a line through `B`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-4,0);

%These commands position vertex C so that the line through A and C is inclined at an angle of 95 degrees
%and the line through B and C is inclined at an angle of 58 degrees.  Since there are 180 degrees in a
%triangle, the measure of angle ACB is 37 degrees.
\path[name path=A-to-C] (A) -- ++(95:5);
\path[name path=B-to-C] (B) -- (58:5);
\path[name intersections={of= A-to-C and B-to-C, by=C}];

%These commands draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%This command draws a line segment horizontally rightwards from A.
\coordinate (D) at (3,0);
\draw (A) -- (D);

%This command draws a line segment upwards from C.
\draw (C) -- ++(95:1.5);

%This command draws a line segment downwards from B.
\draw (B) -- ++(-122:1.5);

%These commands draw the angles for the display.
\coordinate[label={45:$\scriptstyle{x}$}] (A) at (A);
\coordinate[label={45,xshift=4mm:$\scriptstyle{58}$}] (B) at (B);
\coordinate[label={-90,xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm:$\scriptstyle{z}$}] (B) at (B);
\coordinate[label={-90,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm:$\scriptstyle{37}$}] (C) at (C);
\coordinate[label={90,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-1mm:$\scriptstyle{y}$}] (C) at (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is passing through `B`. But at what angle? Please specify.

Comment: And all those `++` are not needed actucally.

Comment: `-` goes clockwise so, if `0` is at 3 o'clock, `-122` will be roughly south west. That's what I get....

Comment: I think that you are looking for `90+58=148` instead of `180-58=122`, in case you want to extend `BC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point `B` is not the origin but `(-4,0)`. There you should use `++` which is not needed for `(0,0)` for angle measurements. Otherwise, your angles go wrong. To check try this

```
\draw[name path=B-to-C] (B) -- (90:7);
```

You won't get 90 degree line.

To correct, use this:

```
\draw[name path=A-to-C] (A) -- (95:5.65);
\draw[name path=B-to-C] (B) -- ++(58:7);   %%<---- Add ++ here
```

Now

```
\draw[red] (B) -- ++(-122:1.5);
```

works.

Change `\draw` to `\path`. They are just for visualizing what you are drawing.

To draw the angle, load `angles` (already loaded) and `quotes` library and do this:

```
\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$37$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = B--C--A};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,positioning,intersections}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-4,0);

%These commands position vertex C so that the line through A and C is inclined at an angle of 95 degrees
%and the line through B and C is inclined at an angle of 58 degrees.  Since there are 180 degrees in a
%triangle, the measure of angle ACB is 37 degrees.
\draw[name path=A-to-C] (A) -- (95:5.65);
\draw[name path=B-to-C] (B) -- ++(58:7);   %%<---- Add ++ here
\path[name intersections={of= A-to-C and B-to-C, by=C}];

%These commands draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%This command draws a line segment horizontally rightwards from A.
\coordinate (D) at (3,0);
\draw (A) -- (D);

%This command draws a line segment upwards from C.
\draw (C) -- +(95:1.5);

%This command draws a line segment downwards from B.
\draw[red] (B) -- ++(-122:1.5);

%These commands draw the angles for the display.
\coordinate[label={45:$\scriptstyle{x}$}] (A) at (A);
%\coordinate[label={45,xshift=4mm:$\scriptstyle{58}$}] (B) at (B);
\coordinate[label={-90,xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm:$\scriptstyle{z}$}] (B) at (B);
%\coordinate[label={-90,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm:$\scriptstyle{37}$}] (C) at (C);
\coordinate[label={90,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-1mm:$\scriptstyle{y}$}] (C) at (C);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$37$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = B--C--A};
\path pic[draw, angle radius=10mm,"$58$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to use the `angles` package.  To position angle `x`, I used the command `\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{x}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = D--A--C};`, to position the angle `y`, I used the commands `\draw (C) -- ++(95:1.5) coordinate (E);` and to position `z`, I used the commands `\draw (B) -- ++(-122:1.5) coordinate (F);` and `\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{z}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = F--B--A};`.  They are typeset two far from the vertices.  Why are they at different distances than `37` and `58`?

Comment: By the way, I decreased the arc radius (for the angles) from 10mm to 5mm.  Also, I made the arcs invisible.

Comment: @Adelyn Adjust `angle eccentricity`.

Comment: You had `angle eccentricity=1.25`. Doesn't this put the label 1.25 times further from the vertex than the specified arc radius?  I kept `angle eccentricity=1.25` for angles `x`, `y`, and `z`.  They were typeset much further from their vertices.

Comment: @Adelyn Change different values and see. lesser value brings the label closer.

Comment: I used `angle eccentricity=1.25` for all the angles.  Why are `37` and `58` placed much closer to their vertices than angles `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: I want to get all of `37`, `58`, `x`, `y`, and `z` the same distance from their vertices.

Comment: @Adelyn Use angles for all. Now `x`, `y` and `z` are included as labels for coordinates. Or put 37 and 58 also as labels. Your call.

Comment: I used `pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{x}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = D--A--C};` to typeset `x`, and I used `\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{37}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = B--C--A};` to typeset `37`, and I used the commands `\draw (C) -- ++(95:1.5) coordinate (E);` and `\path pic[angle radius=5mm,"$\scriptstyle{y}$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = E--C--B};` to typetset `y`.  The `x` and `y` are at a different distance from their vertices than `37` is from its vertex.

Comment: @Adelyn because those angles are different. For same angle the height will be same.  This may deserve to be a new question.